# Make custom seek bar with dots android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

I want to make a custom seekbar whose dots become black after passing that level 
like this...
http://s9.postimg.org/ib3iyg73z/requ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar For your requirement .Its similar to your Desire Output .

Please have a look here

> [How to make segmented seekbar/slider look like following?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472144/how-to-make-segmented-seekbar-slider-look-like-following)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to the seekbar the bitmap to display and change it depending on the level.

Define the listener

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener mOnSeekBarChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
...

  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
     Bitmap bitmap;
     if( int <= 0 )
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.whitecircle);
     else
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blackcircle);

     ThumbBitmapDrawable th = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
     seekBar.setThumb(th);
  }
```

attach the listener to your seekbar

```
theSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mOnSeekBarChangeListener);
```